# How to define and access the database postgresql like flask sample code

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask

I'm new use python flask, I want connected to postgresql use code like flask sample in [this link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/database/), but in code sample use sqlite3. I try to search code sample and make me confused because every sample use different approach. This my code run but when use CLI to initialize database error.

```
Error: No such command "init-db".
```

My structure file

[image]

This my code:

run.py

```
#run.py
import os

from smart_app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**init**.py

```
#__init__.py
from flask import Flask


def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # load default configuration
    app.config.from_object('config.default')

    # load the configuration from the instance folder
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    # Load the file specified by the APP_CONFIG_FILE environment variable
    # Variables defined here will override those in the default configuration
    app.config.from_envvar('APP_CONFIG_FILE')

    # Connect to database
    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)


    return app
```

db.py

## db.py

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

```
# db = SQLAlchemy()

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = SQLAlchemy()

    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you familiar with SQL, use the [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) to connect to your postgresql database.
Or if you want use ORM to operate the database in flask, you can use [`flask_sqlalchemy`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/config/#connection-uri-format).

Comment: Thank you for fast respond...I try your suggestion